# Does scraping using file_get_html or file_get_contents count for traffic on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, scraper-sites

Does scraping using Simple HTML DOM's file_get_html or file_get_contents count for traffic on Google Analytics?

Comment: What are those two methods and where are they documented? I suspect they are in some specific programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, scraping using the PHP functions `file_get_html` or `file_get_contents` will not count as traffic in Google Analytics. (It will, however, be counted as traffic in the *server access logs*.)

The GA tracking code relies on JavaScript being executed in the browser (client-side). When you request a URL using either of these functions, you are simply making a request to the server. Only the server-side code is processed and you receive the *response*. Any JavaScript code in that response is not processed.

Comment: How would GA log the request, since its code is client side and won't be executed? Assuming only the HTML page is being requested, the call isn't going to fetch any noscript alternatives.

Comment: @TimFountain Yes, you are absolutely correct. Not sure what I was thinking - I've rewritten my answer! Thanks.

Comment: @DocRoot great thanks for the input! So is there even a need to use a proxy then? By using a proxy I mean I don't want my own IP detected I'd rather have the proxy's IP detected

Comment: Your IP (or the IP from which you are making the requests) would still be logged in the server's access logs (of the site you are scraping). So, if you don't want to be identified then you will still need to use an anonymising proxy (ie. one that does not pass on your IP address in an HTTP request header, eg. `X-Forwarded-For`).